# How to determine files that apache "cannot open for reading" in error log

Tags: apache, logging, permissions

My apache error log is full of

```
Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
Error opening file for reading: Permission denied
```

etc.

How can I determine the file or folder of files that is causing this permissions error? There's no direct relation between errors appearing and access_log requests.

[Googling suggests](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159572/how-to-determine-file-in-error-opening-file-for-reading-error) I should use **strace** but when I do

```
strace apache2
```

or

```
strace -etrace:open apache2
```

the response is verbose and since I haven't really used this tool successfully before, I'm not sure what to look for. Here's a trace of what appears.

```
.....
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
apache2: bad user name ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
```

The last line is the only one that seems it might be the cause, but my webserver is processing images, and all sorts of disk stuff that would be a problem if the apache user wasn't sufficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not very knowledgeable about strace, but I think you will need to do a few other things to get Apache to run as you want.

If you just run the apache2 binary, your program will stop (as you noted) with a bad user name  because typically the apache username/group are set as part of the config (in /etc/apache2/envvars on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation).

What I found easiest was to find the apachectl script on my machine, and search for "start)". You will find a line that looks like:

`$HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENTS} -k $ARGV`

you can add your strace here so it looks like:

`strace -etrace:open -f $HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENETS} -k $ARGV`

You need to include the -f option as apache will spawn a number of processes and you want to trace them all most likely, at least this is what worked for me :)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I neglected to up-vote at the time, and can't honestly remember what the problem, nor the solution was now!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for calls to `open()` which result in return value -1, errno == EACCES.

I had to tweak the following strace command line on ubuntu (in /usr/sbin/apachectl):

```
strace -o /tmp/strace.log -e trace=open -f $HTTPD ${APACHE_ARGUMENTS} -k $ARGV
```

The `-o` stores the output in a file. Use an appropriate destination directory if you are worried about leaking filenames in an area readable by everyone.

I'm chasing a similar bug myself with a python program running in apache mod wsgi. I'm finding these...

```
3556  open("/proc/self/auxv", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I think my bug has to do with the fact that the wsgi worker process drops privilege from root to the regular user running the app, but after the privilege drop, `/proc/self/auxv` still remains unreadable to regular processes. -- maybe.